# code blocks are disappearing

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown

My "code" blocks are disappearing in this question: [Approach to learning arpeggios for chord-tone soloing (shapes or notes)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11512/approach-to-learning-arpeggios-note-based-pattern-based-or-other)

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I quoted "code" because I'm really just looking for mono-spaced lettering, and what's inside the block is a guitar fretboard diagram, and not code

Comment: Try putting *two spaces* after each of the 5's in your diagrams.  Two spaces forces Markdown to issue a "section break."  I don't have editing rights or I would have done it myself, but it does fix the problem in the question preview.

Comment: I think this will be due to the `jTab` plugin in use on Music.SE; http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/396/jtab-needs-to-render-in-markdown-preview, as the second and third code blocks are getting converted to SVG elements, generated by Raphael...

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Guests are allowed to improve the posts](http://music.stackexchange.com/posts/11512/edit)

Comment: @hjpotter92: Not just to add a few spaces, they can't.  Suggested edits like that are considered too minor; the UI issues an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your fretboards inside `<pre>` blocks.  That should fix the problem for now.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks good now.  I'll accept this answer.